# Issues with EasyUI and ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-easyui

I'm using a EasyUI Tree and I'm trying to set the icons on the parent and child nodes.

The code is as follow:

```
        $('#inventorytree').tree ({
            url: 'inventory.json',
            method: 'get',
            animate: true,
            lines: true,
            formatter: function (node) {
                var s = node.text;
                var nodeicon = 'icon-blank';
                if (node.children){
                    var onlinecount = 0 ;
                    var offlinecount = 0 ;
                    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
                                                        var status = IsOnlineAjaxCall(node.children[i].id);
                        if (status == 'true') {
                            onlinecount += 1;
                            node.children[i].iconCls = 'icon-green-dot';
                        } else {
                            offlinecount += 1;
                            node.children[i].iconCls = 'icon-red-dot';
                        }
                    }
                    var chlidrenlength = node.children.length
                    if (chlidrenlength > 0) {
                        if (onlinecount == chlidrenlength) {
                            node.iconCls = 'icon-green-dot';
                        } else if (offlinecount == chlidrenlength) {
                            node.iconCls= 'icon-red-dot';
                        } else {
                            node.iconCls= 'icon-orange-dot';
                        }
                    }
                    s += '&nbsp;<span style=\'color:blue\'>(' + chlidrenlength + ')</span>';
                }
                return s;
            },
        });
```

I actually check if the nodes (network devices) are online of offline.

Since I'm pinging the devices, I use an Ajax call:

```
function IsOnlineAjaxCall(deviceid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Dashboard_v2.aspx/IsOnline",
        data: '{id: "' + deviceid + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data.d);
            var returnstr = data.d.toString;
            return returnstr;
            //return data.d;
        },
        //success: function (data) {
        //    return data;
        //},
        failure: function (response) {
        //alert(response.d);
        }
});
```

Here are my issues; yes, I have a few:

1) I can't get the tree to start as collapsed.

If I set the status to closed, the best I get is, indeed, a closed status BUT the empty nodes have a plus sign and when clicking it, it lists all the parent nodes.
Calling a function to CollapseAll is never called is outside a button.

2) Getting undefined value from the ajax function

When running an alert from the ajax function, I get the expected result: true or false.
As soon as the value is sent back to the calling function in the tree definition, I get undefined.
Did quite a bit of research and just can't figure out how to fix it.

3) iconCls on the parent node

Setting the iconCls property on the child nodes (manually at this stage) does work just fine.
Setting the iconCls on the parent node is not taken into account. Calling the property value, I get the value I just set but the tree does not display the new icon as it does for the children

Any help is MUCH appreciated

UPDATE on issue #2
I'm using a div to 'store' the result from ajax and then read the value:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Dashboard_v2.aspx/IsOnline",
        data: '{id: "' + deviceid + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("HidIpStatus").innerHTML = data.d;
        },
        failure: function (response) {
        }
    });
```

That work around is working but there must be something better, no?

Answer (score 0):

When you write a function that is depending on the return value from an ajax call, it will fail unless you use [promises](http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/promises-in-wicked-detail/). What is happening here when you call IsOnlineAjaxCall() -- javascript doesn't know that it needs to wait for a response from an ajax call and keeps going, so status == undefined. If you read the documentation here, you'll see some examples of how to fix it using JQuery [deferred.promise()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/). Hard to say but I think at least if you move past this point the rest of it might start falling into place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I did see some docs about promise but did not figure out how to get it implemented...and still don't.

I tried to change the ajax call by using .done and .always but makes the code fail altogether.

Also, since the alert call does provide the correct value, doesn't that mean that the call does complete?